# Is there an easy way to move between sections in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, sections-paragraphs

In Scientific Word, there is a list box for displaying all sections in the article so that moving between sections is very easy. I wonder if there is a similar way to move between sections in TeXstudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this side bar is what you are looking for? I marked the buttons you need to press to show it, if you hid it previously.

[image: TeXStudio GUI]